# Rubidium standard mystery output?

Tags: signal, frequency, waveform, frequency-measurement

I've been playing with a frequency counter (Racal 2202R) that has a built-in rubidium standard.

It has two outputs, "Rb OUT 1" and "Rb OUT 2". I could not find any documentation at all, but the waveforms look like this:

[image: Rb OUT waveforms]

They're clearly both 10 MHz, and "Rb OUT 1" looks like a sine wave.

What might be the other output, any why does it have this peculiar shape?

Comment: Probably ought to be a square wave.  Might be broken, or maybe your scope isn't showing it properly.

Comment: I expect it's supposed to be a digital signal. Can you try probing a known-good 10MHz signal with our scope and the same probe/cable? That would tell us if it's the scope or the counter.  Note that the waveform shown would probably still work OK as a digital output, as the edges are sharp in the 0.8 to 2V range where it really matters.

Comment: It's possible that the digital output needs to be properly terminated (50 ohms?) before it shows a good waveform.

Comment: @ Dave Tweed Yes. That looks like a TTL output, with stronger pulldown than pullup.

Comment: Would it be a digital zero-cross signal?  It seems very well aligned despite its worn out edges.